# How to Serialize/Deserialize an unordered_map member of a derived Class

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, xml-serialization

So I'm building a simulated file-system in C++ to study the language better and maybe some system level programming. Im using Boost::Serialization to save the state of the file system when the user exits, but I'm having trouble in saving/loading my classes.
Here is my base class:

```
enum filetype { FSFILE, FSDIRECTORY, ROOT };

class FileObject {
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) {
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(date_of_creation);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(type);
  }
protected:
  std::string name;
  std::string date_of_creation;
  filetype type;
```

Here is my first derived class that will be basically a `.txt` file in the system:

```
class File : public FileObject {
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) {
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(FileObject);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(content);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(size);
  }

protected:

  std::string content;
  int size;
```

And finally here is the `Directory` class that will act as the directory that holds files and/or other directories:

```
class Directory : public FileObject {
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) {
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(FileObject);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(num_of_contents);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(size_of_contents);
    for (auto it = this->contents.begin(); it != this->contents.end(); it++) {
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(it->second);
    }
  }

protected:
  int num_of_contents;
  int size_of_contents;
public:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, FileObject *> contents;
```

In my main.cc file I have 2 functions, one for saving and one for loading

```
void save_state(const Directory &s, const char * filename){
    // make an archive
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    assert(ofs.good());
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(s);
}
void
restore_state(Directory &s, const char * filename)
{
    // open the archive
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    assert(ifs.good());
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);

    ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(s);
}
```

And finally here is the rest `main.cc` file that creates some files and dirs and saves/loads for testing purposes :

```
int main() {

  char c;

  scanf("%c", &c);
  std::string filename(boost::archive::tmpdir());
  filename += "/demo_save.xml";
  if (c == 's') {
    File file("test_file1", filetype::FSFILE);
    File file2("test_file2", filetype::FSFILE);
    File file3("test_file3", filetype::FSFILE);
    File file4("test_file4", filetype::FSFILE);
    Directory dir("test_dir1", filetype::FSDIRECTORY);
    Directory dir2("test_dir2", filetype::FSDIRECTORY);
    dir.insertContent(file.getName(), &file);
    dir.insertContent(file2.getName(), &file2);
    dir2.insertContent(file3.getName(), &file3);
    dir2.insertContent(file4.getName(), &file4);
    dir.insertContent(dir2.getName(), &dir2);
    save_state(dir, filename.c_str());
  }
  Directory newd;
  if (c == 'l') {
    restore_state(newd, filename.c_str());
    for (auto it = newd.contents.begin(); it != newd.contents.end(); it++) {
      if (it->second->getType() == filetype::FSFILE) {
    std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
    }
      else if (it->second->getType() == filetype::FSDIRECTORY) {
    for (auto jt = ((Directory *)it->second)->contents.begin(); jt != ((Directory *)it->second)->contents.end(); jt++) {
      std::cout << jt->second->getName() << std::endl;
    }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The programm compiles fine but i get seg fault in the second loop. And from reading the `.xml` file, the files inside the `dir2` dont get properly serialized.

Are my classes and functions correct? Is this the correct way to serialize an `unordered_map` that holds pointers to other classes?

Comment: Looks like you're not using virtual inheritance, is that right? It's perfectly fine as a design decision, I just want to make sure I'm reading your code correctly.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [example]? There's certainly stuff you can remove and still get the error, right?

Comment: This line `ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(it->second);` is going to serialize a pointer. The pointer is very unlikely to be the same value between archiving and reloading. The directory holds _references_ to files, it seems, but doesn't actually own them. I'd ask you to think about your architecture first.

Comment: Right now, in your `if (c == 's')` block, your directory is storing pointers to local `File` variables. Those pointers aren't valid once the block scope exits. My question to you is, "Should a directory own its files? If not, what should?" There's no correct answer to this question, except the one you come up with. Figure out the ownership and lifetime of `File`s and `Directory`s first, and THEN you can solve the serialization.

Comment: I'd actually remove all serialization code until you solve your main architecture problems.

Comment: I'm aware of the many architectural issues this code has, I wrote it that way to include as much info as I can. I don't plan using character input to save or load files, I did it just to test if the serialization works which unfortunately it doesn't. Once I fix that and understand how to make it work I refacror the architecture this is for testing purposes.

Comment: Your serialization cannot work BECAUSE your code is broken. Your code is broken BECAUSE your architecture is broken. You cannot fix your serialization until after you've fixed your architecture. If a `Directory` needs to contain zero or more `File`s, then you need a way to serialize that relationship. You can't serialize that relationship until you solidify what the relationship actually is. Unique ownership? Shared ownership? Non-owning reference? Something else?

Comment: Ok noted, thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out you have ownership issues. You **can** serialize pointers but deserializing will result in memory leaks.

Instead, make the pointers owned. I will use `unique_ptr` to manage that instead of writing lots of code to manage the lifetimes correctly.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<FileObject> > contents;
```

Then, you must make sure the hierarchy is virtual, by at least adding

```
virtual ~FileObject() = default;
```

I've elected to make the `FileObject` streamable by also supplying a `print` virtual method.

Lastly, register the types, or mark them abstract as appropriate:

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(FileObject)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(File)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Directory)
```

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b80623057417e27)**

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>

#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

enum filetype { FSFILE, FSDIRECTORY, ROOT };

class FileObject {
  public:
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    virtual ~FileObject() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os, std::string const& prefix = "") const {
        os << "[" << prefix << "/]" << getName() << std::endl;
    }

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar& BOOST_NVP(name) & BOOST_NVP(date_of_creation) & BOOST_NVP(type);
    }

  protected:
    FileObject() = default; // only for deserialization
    FileObject(std::string name, filetype type) : name(std::move(name)), type(type) {
        // TODO date_of_creation
    }

    std::string name;
    std::string date_of_creation;
    filetype    type = ROOT;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FileObject const& fo) {
        fo.print(os);
        return os;
    }
};

class File : public FileObject {
  public:
    File(std::string name, size_t size) : FileObject(std::move(name), FSFILE), size(size) {}

  private:
    File() = default; // only for deserialization
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(FileObject) & BOOST_NVP(content) & BOOST_NVP(size);
    }

  protected:
    std::string content;
    size_t      size = 0;
};

class Directory : public FileObject {
  public:
    Directory() : FileObject("/", ROOT) {}
    Directory(std::string name, filetype type = FSDIRECTORY) : FileObject(name, type) {
        assert(FSDIRECTORY == type);
    }

    bool insertContent(std::unique_ptr<FileObject> object) {
        std::string name = object->getName();
        auto [it, ok] = contents.emplace(std::move(name), std::move(object));
        if (ok)
            num_of_contents += 1; // TODO size_of_contents?
        assert(contents.size() == num_of_contents);
        return ok;
    }

  private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<FileObject> > contents;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(FileObject) & BOOST_NVP(num_of_contents) &
            BOOST_NVP(size_of_contents) & BOOST_NVP(contents);
    }

  protected:
    size_t num_of_contents  = 0;
    size_t size_of_contents = 0;

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os, std::string const& prefix) const override {
        FileObject::print(os, prefix);
        for (auto const& [n, obj] : contents)
            if (obj)
                obj->print(os, prefix + "/" + getName());
    }
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(FileObject)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(File)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Directory)

#include <fstream>

static inline void save_state(Directory const& s, fs::path const& filename) {
    std::ofstream                ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << BOOST_NVP(s);
}

static inline void restore_state(Directory& s, fs::path const& filename) {
    std::ifstream                ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> BOOST_NVP(s);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::set<std::string_view> const args(argv + 1, argv + argc);

    auto filename = fs::temp_directory_path() / "demo_save.xml";

    if (args.contains("save")) {
        Directory dir("test_dir1", filetype::FSDIRECTORY);
        for (auto name : {"test_file1", "test_file2", "test_file3", "test_file4"})
            dir.insertContent(std::make_unique<File>(name, filetype::FSFILE));
        dir.insertContent(std::make_unique<Directory>("test_dir2"));

        save_state(dir, filename);
    }

    if (args.contains("load")) {
        Directory newd;
        restore_state(newd, filename);

        std::cout << newd;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
[/]test_dir1
[/test_dir1/]test_file1
[/test_dir1/]test_file2
[/test_dir1/]test_file3
[/test_dir1/]test_dir2
[/test_dir1/]test_file4
```

And the xml contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="19">
<s class_id="0" tracking_level="1" version="0" object_id="_0">
    <FileObject class_id="1" tracking_level="1" version="0" object_id="_1">
        <name>test_dir1</name>
        <date_of_creation></date_of_creation>
        <type>1</type>
    </FileObject>
    <num_of_contents>5</num_of_contents>
    <size_of_contents>0</size_of_contents>
    <contents class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>5</count>
        <bucket_count>13</bucket_count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item class_id="3" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <first>test_file4</first>
            <second class_id="4" tracking_level="0" version="0">
                <tx class_id="5" class_name="File" tracking_level="1" version="0" object_id="_2">
                    <FileObject object_id="_3">
                        <name>test_file4</name>
                        <date_of_creation></date_of_creation>
                        <type>0</type>
                    </FileObject>
                    <content></content>
                    <size>0</size>
                </tx>
            </second>
        </item>
        <item>
            <first>test_dir2</first>
            <second>
                <tx class_id_reference="0" object_id="_4">
                    <FileObject object_id="_5">
                        <name>test_dir2</name>
                        <date_of_creation></date_of_creation>
                        <type>1</type>
                    </FileObject>
                    <num_of_contents>0</num_of_contents>
                    <size_of_contents>0</size_of_contents>
                    <contents>
                        <count>0</count>
                        <bucket_count>1</bucket_count>
                        <item_version>0</item_version>
                    </contents>
                </tx>
            </second>
        </item>
        <item>
            <first>test_file3</first>
            <second>
                <tx class_id_reference="5" object_id="_6">
                    <FileObject object_id="_7">
                        <name>test_file3</name>
                        <date_of_creation></date_of_creation>
                        <type>0</type>
                    </FileObject>
                    <content></content>
                    <size>0</size>
                </tx>
            </second>
        </item>
        <item>
            <first>test_file2</first>
            <second>
                <tx class_id_reference="5" object_id="_8">
                    <FileObject object_id="_9">
                        <name>test_file2</name>
                        <date_of_creation></date_of_creation>
                        <type>0</type>
                    </FileObject>
                    <content></content>
                    <size>0</size>
                </tx>
            </second>
        </item>
        <item>
            <first>test_file1</first>
            <second>
                <tx class_id_reference="5" object_id="_10">
                    <FileObject object_id="_11">
                        <name>test_file1</name>
                        <date_of_creation></date_of_creation>
                        <type>0</type>
                    </FileObject>
                    <content></content>
                    <size>0</size>
                </tx>
            </second>
        </item>
    </contents>
</s>
</boost_serialization>
```

Comment: would this work if we insert some files on dir2 before we insert it into dir1?

Comment: Sure, why not? Have you tried? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79df4ada3044682e Here's a demo traversing actual filesystem folders: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e0948e8ff90df6c

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Ill study the demo thank you very much!